# MySQL giving error after saying it was successfull

Tags: c#, mysql

The code below is ran when user presses the Login button:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection connection;
string server = "s570.use8.mysecurecloudhost.com";
string database = "nextgene_NGH";
string uid = "nextgene_NGH";
string password = "EXAMPLE PASSWORD";
string ssl = "None";
string connectionString;
connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
            database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";" + "SSL Mode=" + ssl;
int i;
connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

try
{
    i = 0;
    connection.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("Connection Successful!");
    MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `core_members` where name='" + maskedTextBox1.Text + "' and exact_password='" + maskedTextBox2.Text + "'";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());

    if (i == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login Failed.");
        //button2.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login Successful.");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error, Something Happened!");
}

connection.Close();
```

Obviously, I have changed my password since I'm sharing this code online but the password works.It get's to show :

```
MessageBox.Show("Connection Successful!");
```

and then immediately shows:

```
MessageBox.Show("Error, Something Happened!");
```

Below is a photo of the actual database:

[My Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh9MR.png)

what is wrong with my code as it automatically gives after after showing the connection was successful?

I was hoping it was successful and allow me to log in successfully...

Comment: So what is the actual error? (Also **please** use parameters rather than constructing SQL by joining strings together)

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Warning, concatenating values into your DML is an open door for Sql Injection.

Comment: I know it's said above, but because it's so important: Use parameterized queries.  Without them you are subject to SQL injection attacks.  If you think you're safe because no one will visit your little website, automated bots will prove you wrong.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString())` _Really?_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Catching an error that just says "an error happened" is useless. Obviously you know that the database connection succeeded, so the error must be something *after* that.

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error, Something Happened!");
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Now that you can see the *actual* error you can dig further, but I see two potential reasons for the failure:

1. You are concatenating strings instead of using parameters, which is bad enough, but doing it when dealing with passwords is a mortal sin. It's possible that the password contains special characters (like a single quote) that don't work well with string concatenation
2. You are loading the results to a datatable just to see if a row exists. A simpler way would just to `SELECT COUNT(*)`, use `ExecuteScalar`, and look at the result (0 means no rows fit the criteria). It's possible that the DataTable is not filled the way you expect when there are no results.

You should also look up using the dispose pattern so that your connections are closed gracefully when you're done. That's probably not the problem here but it's a good habit to get into.

Comment: `ex.Message` is usually more useful than `ex` itself.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of improvements in here:

```
string server = "s570.use8.mysecurecloudhost.com";
string database = "nextgene_NGH";
string uid = "nextgene_NGH";
string password = "EXAMPLE PASSWORD";
string ssl = "None";

string connectionString = $"SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={uid};PASSWORD={password};SSL Mode={ssl};";

// NEVER NEVER NEVER store an "exact password" in a database!!
string SQL = "SELECT * FROM `core_members` where name= @name AND hashed_password= @hash;";
var dt = new DataTable();

try
{
    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = new MySqlCommand(SQL, connection))
    using (var da = new MySqlDataAdapter(command))
    {
        //NEVER NEVER NEVER use string concatenation to put user input in a query
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",  maskedTextBox1.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hash", HashPassword(maskedTextBox2.Text));
  
        da.Fill(dt); //Fill opens and closes the connection
    }

    if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login Failed.");
        //button2.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Login Successful.");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

The change that most directly relates to the issue at hand is the changing the "Something happened" error to instead give you a meaningful message... but some of the others are probably *more important*, including better password handling, proper connection disposal, and parameterized queries.

Comment: {gasp} `AddWithValue`...  j/k I don't think it's as big a deal as it's usually made out to be.

Comment: @DStanley It **IS** a big deal, but MySql handles parameter binding differently.

Comment: Also not sure why `select *` is needed, probably best to just do `select 1` and then you can use `ExecuteNonScalar` and comapre with `1`

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn while that does work, it seems my password is hashed on the database online and in which case the plaintext password does not work but It seems that if I enter in the hash in the password, then it shows login successfull

Comment: @RyanEllis What you are expected to do is take the password entered by the user and apply the same hashing algorithm and salt that was used on the database. Then compare the hashes. Commonly, this information is stored as part of the password hash. You should **NEVER** store or compare plain-text values directly.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn but I am now having issues with that.

Comment: @RyanEllis That's a different question... but I can see on your user account you've already asked it, and there's seems to be a good answer